# Package Publishing (Python) failing through Poetry

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I am new to this, trying to publish a package to pypi.org using Poetry package.
on my local the build is working, I am able to import the package test run it, it's all good.

but when I try to publish it to pypi.org, I get below error - as per the article I was following [Link](https://www.brainsorting.dev/posts/publish-a-package-on-pypi-using-poetry/#:%7E:text=Publish%20a%20package%20on%20PyPi%20using%20Poetry%201,Publish%20your%20package%20...%205%20End%20notes%20), it was supposed to prompt me for my pypi account ID and password, but it doesn't and then gives the error:

```
Publishing gsst (0.2.2) to PyPI
 - Uploading gsst-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl 0%
 - Uploading gsst-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl 100%
```

and then this error shows up --

```
HTTP Error 403: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information. | b'<html>\n <head>\n  <title>403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.\n \n <body>\n  <h1>403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.\n  Access was denied to this resource.<br/><br/>\nInvalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.\n\n\n \n'
```

after i run the -- poetry publish command, the CLI should prompt me for pypi, ID and password. why does it skip it and then fails on authentication.

Comment: _as per the article I was following_ What article?

Comment: Did you try using the `-u` or `--username` options to provide a username? Also worth using the `-v` (or the more verbose `-vv`) option to see if that helps identify the issue. The username might be getting picked up from the environment.

Comment: I suspect the author had already configured poetry to remember his pypi username and password, and forgot to explain that part.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you John, appreciate it - i read the article again, it does show however that after he issues poetry publish command, it is prompting for username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem finally - Took help from poetry documentation [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli#publish)

Issued the below command to setup my pypi.org account for auto authentication

```
poetry config http-basic.pypi <username> <password>
```

After that I ran the "poetry publish" command and was able to publish my package on pypi.org.

It's really the quickest and easiest way to post your package to pypi.org